# 2007 Hyundai Tucson - Left rear alignment is maxed out

Tags: hyundai, alignment, tucson

I just had my 2007 Hyundai Tucson front end alignment done and rotated the tires. After the alignment, it steered straight, but did not feel right.

The mechanic said the left rear cannot be done anymore. It is maxed out. They said I need to take it to a dealer; they have special tools to do this.

Here are the results:

- Actual = -1.3
- Before = -1.3
- Specified Range = -1.4, -0.4

Below that in red ink is:

- Actual = 0.04
- Before = 0.06
- Specified = 0.14, 0.30

Do I need to replace the camber bolts? What else could it be?

Comment: can you upload a picture of the alignment sheet? what do you mean by, it didn't feel right?

Comment: Thinking we should close this, OP didn't respond to the comment and it's unclear what the problem actually is (does not feel right, which measurements).

Comment: It is a little vague, but it's clear that: 1) The left rear is out of spec, and 2) the mechanic said it was "maxed out" and to take it to dealer, and 3) the OP does not know what this means. Just wanted to point these out in case it clarifies it at all, I dunno. I suppose the OP could just give the dealer a call and see what they say.